# cannot sync from android repository

Tags: android, git, repository

I'm trying to make sync according http://source.android.com/download manual,
so everything is good, except syncing :)

```
repo sync
...
Fetching projects:   5% (8/143)  
Initializing project platform/development ...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Cannot fetch platform/development
.. or
Fetching projects:   2% (3/143)  fatal: read error (Connection reset by peer)
error: Cannot fetch platform/bootable/diskinstaller
```

I've found this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=989), but there is not valuable information

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add any information on your network set-up? Any proxies, firewalls, etc?  Can you ping android.git.kernel.org reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems there is a workaround for this bug (Add missing return False to preconnect):

- https://review.source.android.com/#change,10353
- http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/9924877a1e8e678a

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just keep retrying, even when i have got 100% successful repo sync, retry again may gives error:

Eg,

```
repo sync
Fetching projects: 100% (171/171), done.  

honeyman:/root/download/android/myandroid>repo sync
Fetching projects:   7% (12/171)  fatal: protocol error: bad line length character
error: Cannot fetch device/htc/passion-common

honeyman:/root/download/android/myandroid>repo sync
Fetching projects:  10% (18/171)  fatal: protocol error: bad line length character
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/blktrace

honeyman:/root/download/android/myandroid>repo sync
Fetching projects:  48% (83/171)  fatal: protocol error: bad line length character
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/safe-iop

honeyman:/root/download/android/myandroid>repo sync
Fetching projects:  30% (52/171)  fatal: protocol error: bad line length character
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/iptables

honeyman:/root/download/android/myandroid>repo sync
Fetching projects:   1% (2/171)  fatal: protocol error: bad line length character
error: Cannot fetch platform/bootable/bootloader/legacy
```

Luckily I found the reason is because of my unreliable ethernet RJ45 port (do a "dmesg"):

```
[ 8957.756324] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[ 8959.616964] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 8959.616977] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[ 8974.796164] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[ 8993.905005] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 8993.905019] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[ 9020.320169] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[ 9125.809081] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 9125.809094] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[10033.472196] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[10089.552945] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[10089.552959] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[13714.044175] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[13715.696949] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[13715.696963] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

The answer is to retry again.